# Dart tools didn't work because of .idea folder in my projects folder

Tags: flutter, dart

When I create a new project, for some reason I can't use any dart sdk tools, but when I run my code it still works.

This happens only to new projects, not old ones.
Both flutter and dart extensions installed on vscode.

I am new to programming, if there is any information that may help, please ask!

I did run flutter doctor and flutter analyze; no issues.
I also ran flutter clear then flutter run; didn't work either.

Comment: use Android Studio it helps with all of Your questions

Comment: I am used to vscode + switching to android studio didn't fix it

Comment: add more details to Your question, "didn't work either" not valid explanation, You've to provide technical logs at least

Comment: Literally everything else was working fine, I checked for missing dev dependencies; all there, ran the project and it worked normally. Did all the analysis I knew of using cmd; no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered that I accidently opened my projects folder using vscode, so I checked for a .idea file.
I found it and deleted it then everything worked again magically.

Comment: With my case, remove `.idea` folder as answer of @Zavier.
After re-open project with Android Studio, and add new `.idea` folder to git use: `git add --all .idea/ -f`.
After switch between branch of git, there will be no more errors like the above.